# FieldError at /category_list

Tags: python, django

I am facing this probelm in my e-commerce project when i try to pagination

Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are: created_at, description, id, is_active, subcategories, thumbnail, title, url_slug

```
# CATEGORIES
class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Categories
    template_name = "admin_local/category_list.html"
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_val = self.request.GET.get("filter", "")`enter code here`
        order_by = self.request.GET.get("orderby", "id")
        if filter_val != "":
            cat = Categories.objects.filter(
                Q(title__contains=filter_val) | Q(description__contains=filter_val)).order_by(order_by)

        else:
            cat = Categories.objects.all().order_by(order_by)

        return cat

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoriesListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["filter"] = self.request.GET.get("filter", "")
        context["orderby"] = self.request.GET.get("orderby", "")
        context["all_table_fields"] = Categories._meta.get_fields()
        return context
```

I am facing this probelm in my e-commerce project when i try to pagination
This Is html file

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                         href="{% url 'category_list' %}?filter={{ filter }}&orderby={{ orderby }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }} ">Previous</a>
                                </li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"
                                                                  href="#">Previous</a>
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                              {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                         href="{% url 'category_list' %}?filter={{ filter }}&orderby={{ orderby }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }} ">Next</a>
                                </li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"
                                                                  href="#">Previous</a>
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this is because you use `orderby={{ orderby }}` which is empty if it is not filled in.

You should pass the context with:

```
context['orderby'] = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'id')
```

furthermore you should `|urlencode` the parameters:

```
<a class="page-link" href="{% url 'category_list' %}?filter={{ filter|urlencode }}&orderby={{ orderby|urlencode }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }} ">Next</a>
```

You might also want to avoid ordering by an arbitrary field, since ordering can expose sensitive information, for example trying to order by the (hashed) password of a user.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: @DevMalik: exactly *what* do you not understand?

Comment: here now what i do? that my error resolved

Comment: @DevMalik: you replace `context["orderby"] = self.request.GET.get("orderby", "")` with `context['orderby'] = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'id')`...

Comment: Thanks Sir now its Working Bundle of thanks